# Show product category under each product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to show each products category, right under the product image on the shop page.

**[Here's the current page](http://watchband.dk/butik/)**

**[Here's where I want to display the category name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhKBs.jpg)**

I have tried with the following code, but it doesn't seem like it can get the current product category from the functions.php file.

**And here it comes...**

```
function sv_add_text_under_wc_shop_image() {

    echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ) ) . ' ', '</span>' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'sv_add_text_under_wc_shop_image', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of content-product.php to your child theme and find this line:

```
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
```

Add this right after it:

```
<?php
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'product_cat');
        $count = count($terms); $i=0;
        if ($count > 0) {
            $term_list = '<div class="parent_category">';
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $i++;
                if ($term->parent==0) {
                    $term_list .= '<a href="/?product_cat=' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                    if ($count != $i) $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
                }
            }
            echo $term_list .'</div>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: There isn't such a line in content-product.php